# Doctrine - Invalid column name 'sclr0'

Tags: doctrine, sum, sql-order-by

My query doesn't work when i use `->setMaxResult` with `orderBy SUM`.

My dataBase is MSSQL SERVER 2008 R2

`$query = $entity->createQueryBuilder('t')
                        ->select('SUM(t.price) AS test')
                        ->setMaxResults(10)
                        ->orderBy('test', 'ASC')->getQuery()->getResult();`

> Invalid column name 'sclr0'.

but when i comment this method `setMaxResult()` my query works fine.

Please help-me, I sorry my english.

Comment: What doctrine version do you have? Could be this [bug](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2622), which was fixed in doctrine 2.4.

Comment: in Doctrine\DBAL\Version.php const VERSION = '2.5.1'; but doesn't work when i use "AS", but in sum or count a need to use alias.

Comment: And `->orderBy('SUM(t.price)', 'ASC')` works?

Comment: I tested it too, but Doctrine returns
Error : Expected known function , we got ' SUM

Comment: @BelitaColares are you sure you don't need a group by for sum method because if you use any aggregate function without group by you will have only one row in the result set therefore  `->setMaxResults(10)` doesn't makes sense when you have 1 row in result set

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I understand, but when i use only '->select('t.price AS test')
                        ->setMaxResults(10)
                        ->orderBy('test', 'ASC');' doesn't work, Doctrine return Invalid column name 'PRICE_0'.

Comment: @BelitaColares try this remove `getResult()` and call `getSql()` see query generated by doctrine

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid `SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT t0_.PRICE AS PRICE_0,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                             ORDER BY PRICE_0 ASC) AS doctrine_rownum
   FROM TITMMOV t0_) AS doctrine_tbl
WHERE doctrine_rownum BETWEEN 1 AND 10
ORDER BY doctrine_rownum`